# How to rename the tabs under Details on product details page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I use a Porto theme for my Magento 2 store and wondering if there's an easy way to rename the Details tabs on product details page.

[image: Actual screenshot of where I want to rename]

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">                
      <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Your Review tab name</argument>
        </arguments>
      </referenceBlock>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks HImanshu, I need to rename 'Reviews' tab as well. How can that be done?

Comment: Answers updated please check.

Comment: Thanks himanshu, but it didn't work. Tried couple of other options too as told by madani but that too didn't go well.

Comment: check in porto theme,,, theme already override catalog_product_view.xml this file so you can add this code in current activated file

Answer (score 0):

1. you can change the tabs name in products attribute code
   description,meta_description, and short_description

[image]

2. Otherwise you can change your tabs name in your translation csv file.

Comment: Thanks madani, could you spell out where I can find these code files? Path or anything would help. I looked under app/design/porto/magento_catalog and magento_layout etc but could not exactly get to any files you are asking.

Comment: add your rename words in  app/design/frontend/your theme name/ i18n/en_US.csv like,
"Details","your rename word"
"More Information","Your rename Word"
"Review","Your rename word"

Comment: I have also checked under product description, meta description and short description but couldn't find anything where I can rename the tabs. Where i should look for translation csv?

Comment: Checked under en_US.csv but could not find Details, More Information and Review under this file to rename it.

Comment: second way is you can add the label name in attribute as mention in above SS.

Comment: if you could not find words you can add this words in csv file.

Comment: Not working by adding label name in attribute as there are no attributes for More Information tab or Reviews tab. I added words to csv file too but it's not renaming on frontend. Cleared the cache as well.

Comment: you have which language store?

Comment: Store is in English language.

Comment: Locale is English (Australia)

Comment: once run the 
bin/magento s:up
bin/magento s:s:d -f {your language code}
bin/magento c:f
 and also create the csv file name your language code in i18n folder after run the commands.

Comment: your issue resolve or not ?

Comment: No not yet did try all of the things as you said but it's not working that way.

Comment: CSV translation is working for me.

Comment: I had created en_AU comma delimited csv file same as en_US and entered Reviews "Reviews & Testimonials" More Information "Added information" Details "Description" Is this how you are suggesting as well?

Comment: Add  like this,
"Review","{your translation}"
"Details","{your translation}"
"More Information","{your translation}"

after run the magento commands

Answer (score 0):

Add  this in your en_AU csv translation file

**"Review","your translation"**

**"Details","your translation"**

**"More Information","your translation"**

After run the magento commands